# What is this tube coming off from 1 of 2 motorcycle carburettors?

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor

I've inherited a 1979 Yamaha xs400 that needs some attention. Whilst preparing to remove the engine I came across this tube that protrudes from where one of the 2 carbs meets the block. The 2nd carb has a nozzle where a 2nd tube could go, but this has been blocked off with a cap.

Would anyone know what this is for?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... Mr google said:

> The OEM petcock is vacuum actuated. With a properly operating petcock,
>   unless the engine is producing vacuum the petcock will not flow
>   gasoline while in the ON or RES positions. When in the PRI position
>   gas will flow even when the engine is not runing. The tube the shop is
>   talking about is a vacuum tube running from the left carb intake boot
>   to the petcock. It is not unusual for the vacuum actuated portion of
>   the petcock to fail and the owner to clip and plug the vacuum line
>   going to the intake boot to eliminate the associated vacuum leak.

[image]

Hope that helps.